# Why is event handling in native Visual C++ deprecated?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, events, event-handling, deprecated

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee2k0a7d.aspx

> Event handling is also supported for
>   native C++ classes (C++ classes that
>   do not implement COM objects),
>   however, **that support is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future
>   release**.

Anyone knows why? Couldn't find any explanation for this statement.

Comment: The latest version also states that it's deprecated, but it's still there, 8 years later https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/event-handling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's totally non-standard kludge that probably has very little actual
   users. And I mean non-stndard kludge even in WinNT and Microsoft-private world.
2. COM has much richer repertoire for event-like mechanisms and also allow
   fully multi-threaded code these days
3. This one is lethal - that functionality is doing implicit locking (probably our grandpa's idea
   of "synchonized" before templates and widespread safe use of normal critical sections). That
   makes it more dangerous than COM's single apartment, ahem, thing :-) As in it can give you a deadlock out of nowhere (happened to Java's synchronized methods as well - nothing special :-)
4. Everyone and their dogs know how to use normal multi-threading and at least critical sections with smart pointers these days, so besides being dangerous, that thing is also irrelevant.

Comment: +1, though I'd disagree with "irrelevant" - a native mechanism would be welcome. It can be implemented through libraries, but first class support with elegant syntax, good compiler diagnostics, debug support ("break when this even fires") etc. would be welcome.

Comment: It's really nothing more than async call for which you don't check completion. Forgot the name of a API - just fires up a thread which gets closed when the function returns - perfecly debuggable and no locking if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hazard a guess, and it is just that, that similar functionality can be achieved by a signal/slots type library in a more more portable/standard C++ (with templates) fashion rather than requiring compiler support by MS.

Comment: More likely looking at the MSDN page as MS expect you do do the events and marshalling in COM

Answer (score 1):

I'd hazard a guess that they would want you to do it all the .Net way now.

Comment: haha +1, I think NET and similar managed code is the biggest disaster that happened in programming history.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Boost::Signals2](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.signals2)

(This is the successor of Boost Signals, which is no longer maintained)

Comment: FYI, this link is now broken.

Comment: both boost signals and sigc++ are the best ones to choose from.