# Handling __event in Qt MinGW compiler

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, bluetooth, mingw

A 3rd party library(https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm) I am using using has __event mechanism, which I believe is MSVC specific, used widely. Do we have any solution by which we can manage or listen to these events in a MinGW environment.

Development environment is as below
Platform : Qt using MinGW compiler
OS: Windows

Comment: I doubt it, MinGW and MSVC are pretty different. What you can do is use Qt with MSVC. I'm surprised because the lib you're wanting to add says it's only standard C++, not MSVC++. Did you try using the lib with MinGW ?

Answer (score 1):

The native `__event` mechanism [is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2295639/1329652), so you should be using the COM event system instead, and there's nothing compiler-specific to that. The vendor of the library should be able to provide you with examples of modern event handling code, if they are serious about supporting their product.